# Query for the work to be done soon

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following structure

```
EMP_ID  EMP_NAME EMP_PHONE
 1         A      5656565
 2         B      8751465
 3         C      9621496
```

I want to delete the entire `EMP_NAME` values only. NO change should be done in records for 
`EMP_ID` & `EMP_PHONE`.

Answer (score 3):

```
update YourTable
set EMP_NAME = null
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are never going to use EMP_NAME again.

ALTER TABLE yourTable drop column EMP_NAME

---

If you want to clear the values, but later want to use a compare statement for the repopulating of the values, avoid 'null' issues with

update yourTable set Emp_NAME=''

---

If you want to clear the values, and know how to handle 'null',

update yourTable set EMP_NAME=null

Answer (score 1):

```
update xxxxx set EMP_NAME is null
```